# Javascript fetch server data with php session

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get server information via fetch but if on the php page is a session started nothing returns.

Simplified example of my code:

JS:

```
fetch(url)
```

PHP:

```
session_start();
echo json_encode( array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5) );
```

As soon as I remove session part, the json is returned.

When I use XMLHttpRequest everything is working as expected:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Maybe I have to change the fetch parameters, but I already tried different but nothing changed.

Comment: Does the PHP return information with session_start() and the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Differences_from_jQuery

Comment: XMLHttpRequest works without a problem with the session.

Comment: The differences from jQuery should not be a problem? Because I dont want to send or receive cookies. The session is only used on the server to get data from a different external service. And on the other hand I use one the plain XMLHttpRequest without jQuery at all

Comment: Have you confirmed nothing returns using the network tab in your browsers devtools? Does it return a 500? Does it return a 200 with empty body? What changed fetch parameters have you already tried? As a side: start_session will be useless unless you allow credentials in the xhr call (that being cookies, the PHPSESSID cookie specifically).

Comment: Yes in network nothing return, even if I echo something before the session_start. As soon as session_start is included nothing returns with a 200 status. I tried all content types in the header, credentials, mode.

Comment: That is very odd. Odd indeeeeed, but somehow familiar like I saw a mention of this once before in another SO question, but I can't find it now grrr.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't see response in browser console.

Try

```
fetch(url).then(function(res){
    return res.json();
});
```

and you will see.

I found this is because of header:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
```

Calling `session_cache_limiter('')` before `session_start()` will prevent auto sending any caching headers. Calling with other parameters except `'nocache'` will send allowing cache headers.

Also control available through php ini directive `session.cache_limiter`